# Issues getting timediff to work properly and group averages

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a query to determine how long a computer takes to complete a process.  The data looks something like this:

```
 id        wks               action     timestamp
1490    WN-OR14P5Y2N248     Begin       2013-10-18 17:07:47.000
1491    WN-OR14P5Y2N248     Convert     2013-10-18 17:08:40.000
1505    WN-OR14P5Y2N248     Complete    2013-10-21 07:20:39.000
498     WN-OR16LS3HV142     Begin       2013-10-10 18:29:06.000
499     WN-OR16LS3HV142     Convert     2013-10-10 18:29:39.000
1303    WN-OR16LS3HV142     Complete    2013-10-16 14:44:09.000
```

This goes on for a few thousand computers or so.

My query so far starts like this:

```
 select *, TIMEDIFF(x.timestamp, y.timestamp)as timed from sslog x
 inner join sslog y on
 x.wks = y.wks
 where x.action = 'begin'
 and y.action = 'complete'
```

But when I run this, I get the error: "Bad format for Time '-25:06:26' in column 9" and I can't figure it out.  Any idea?

Comment: Can you add the show create table to your question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I needed to use timestampdiff rather than timediff.